# Доступ к общему ресурсу при многопоточности(пул потоков)

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-8, multiprocessing

Программа решает следующую задачу: есть несколько файлов с текстом, на каждый файл через пул потоков создается поток для открытия и чтения файла и составление из прочитанного текста списка из строк `List<String>`,
 далее предполагается использование общего для всех потоков `Map<String, Long>` для сбора статистики следующим образом - ключом(key) будет соответственно строка из списка, а значение(value) равно 1, но если такой ключ уже присутствует т.е. в списке и в других списках имеются одинаковые строки, то инкрементировать значение на единицу

Если  первый файл содержит строки "Hello", второй соответственно две строки "Java" и "World", а третий файл "Hello", то результирующий map должен выглядеть так:

```
{"Hello"=2,"Java"=1, "World"=1}
```

**Вот мой код:**

В методе makeStatistics()создается экземпляр класса (Statistic), где находится общий map, далее метод makeStatistics() с помощью метода getFilesPaths() вычисляет пути к файлам с расширением .txt и заносит из в список, далее создает фиксированный пул потоков размером, равным количеству текстовых файлов в папке(1 файл - 1 поток), потом в цикле создаются экземпляры классов для потока ReaderThread, в его конструктор передается экземпляр класса (Statistic) с общим map-ом и путь к файлу

```
    public ArrayList<Path> getFilesPaths() {
    ArrayList<Path> filesNames = null;
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\DIR"))) {
        filesNames= files
                    .filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        filesNames.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filesNames;
}

public void makeStatistics() {

    Statistic statistic = new Statistic();

    ArrayList<Path> logPaths = getFilesPaths();
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(logPaths.size());

    for (Path filePath : logPaths)
    {
        ReaderThread logReader = new ReaderThread(statistic, filePath);
        executor.execute(logReader);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Класс потока выглядит так, он просто читает файл, по переданному в него пути и сохраняет строчки в список, потом в строке statistic.setStatisticMap(textLines); список отправляется на изменение общего map-а в классе Statistic

```
public class ReaderThread implements Runnable {

private Path filePath;
private Statistic statistic;

public ReaderThread(Statistic statistic, Path filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    this.statistic = statistic;
}

public Path getFile() {
    return filePath;
}

public void run() {   
        List<String> textLines;
        try(Stream<String> lineStream = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath).lines()) {
            textLines = lineStream
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

            statistic.setStatisticMap(textLines);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

А вот и класс с общим map-ом:

```
public class Statistic {

private Map<String, Long> statisticMap;

public Statistic() {
    statisticMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public synchronized void setStatisticMap(List<String> logLines) {
    statisticMap = logLines.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));

    System.out.println(statisticMap);
}

public Map<String, Long> getStatisticMap() {
    return statisticMap;
}
```

}

При запуске выводит:

```
{Hello=1}
{Java=1, World=1}
{Hello=1}
```

т.е. как я понимаю map не становится общим, а создается каждому потоку по личному map-у
Как сделать statisticMap - общим для всех потоков?

Comment: `statisticMap` у вас и так общий. Только 1) HashMap не потокобезопасная коллекция, используйте ConcurrentHashMap. 2) `statisticMap = logLines.stream()` вот тут, каждый ваш поток, создаёт свою мапу, и присваивает statisticMap ссылку на неё. Таким образом, после выполнения всех потоков, у вас останется ссылка только на map из файла, который обработался последним.

Comment: @SpringNewbie , спасибо, но даже если я заменяю `HashMap` на `ConcurrentHashMap` картина не меняется; 
так а как исправить `statisticMap = logLines.stream()`? Если я заменю эту реализацию на классическую Java без StreamAPI общий ресурс заработает как мне нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск значения в мапе и его инкремент так же должны быть атомарны.

Пример реализация класса:

```
class Statistic {

    private Map<String, Long> statisticMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void setStatisticMap(List<String> logLines) {

        logLines.forEach(line -> {
            statisticMap.putIfAbsent(line, 0L);
            statisticMap.computeIfPresent(line, (key, value) -> value + 1);
        });
        System.out.println(statisticMap);
    }


    public Map<String, Long> getStatisticMap() {
        return statisticMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я заменил реализацию метода `setStatisticMap(List<String> logLines)` на классическую Java БЕЗ использования StreamAPI и все заработало как надо!

```
    public void setStatisticMap(List<String> textLines) {

    for (String key : textLines) {
        if (statisticMap.containsKey(key)) {
            statisticMap.put(key, statisticMap.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            statisticMap.put(key, 1L);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(statisticMap);
}
```

Спасибо @SpringNewbie за подсказку!